# How can I replace duplicate strings of words in each row using regular expressions with vi?

Tags: regex, vim, replace, duplicates

How can I replace duplicate strings of words in each row using regular expressions with vi?
For instance, I have the following list of seaports that have duplicate text.

My goal is to achieve the following output below:

(input) Duplicated List

```
Andorra La Vella Andorra La Vella
Al Ain Al Ain
Abu al Bukhoosh Abu al Bukhoosh
Ajman Ajman
Arzanah Island Arzanah Island
Abu Dhabi Abu Dhabi
Das Island Das Island
Al Dhafra Al Dhafra
Ras Zubbaya (Ras Dubayyah) Ras Zubbaya (Ras Dubayyah)
Dubai Dubai
Fateh Terminal Fateh Terminal
Fujairah (Al-Fujairah) Fujairah (Al-Fujairah)
Musafa Musafa
Hamriyah Hamriyah
Jebel Ali Jebel Ali
Jebel Dhanna Jebel Dhanna
Khor Al Fakkan Khor Al Fakkan
Masfut Masfut
Mubarras Island Mubarras Island
```

(output) Corrected List

```
Andorra La Vella
Al Ain
Abu al Bukhoosh
Ajman
Arzanah Island
Abu Dhabi
Das Island
Al Dhafra
Ras Zubbaya (Ras Dubayyah)
Dubai
Fateh Terminal
Fujairah (Al-Fujairah)
(...)
```

Any insight?

(full list of ports available in http://www.photius.com/seaports/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply a substitution command for each line of the file:

```
:%s/\v(.*)\s*\1/\1/
```

It yields:

```
Andorra La Vella 
Al Ain 
Abu al Bukhoosh 
Ajman 
Arzanah Island 
Abu Dhabi 
Das Island 
Al Dhafra 
Ras Zubbaya (Ras Dubayyah) 
Dubai 
Fateh Terminal 
Fujairah (Al-Fujairah) 
Musafa 
Hamriyah 
Jebel Ali 
Jebel Dhanna 
Khor Al Fakkan 
Masfut 
Mubarras Island
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked! Can you explain the "magic" function of \v ?

Comment: @AntónioGonçalves: It means **very magic** and does most characters get its special meaning, if any, and avoids to escape them. Look at `help magic` in `vim`.

Comment: @AntónioGonçalves: If this worked for you, you should accept the answer so people how have similar issues in the future can see.